Avoid "variable is assigned, but its value is never used" [PHP]
In VS with PHPTools activated I have following code part:
foreach ($row['bgcolor'] as &$colBgColor) {
    $colBgColor = Color::COLOR_HEADER;
}

In the VS Error List I get following warning:
PHP0421 The variable '$colBgColor' is assigned, but its value is never used
I know that I could avoid this warning by refactoring the code. But what makes me wonder is how I can remove this warning with an annotation, a PHPTools configuration or something else other than code refactoring.
I tried following annotations above foreach without success:

@psalm-suppress PHP0421
@phpstan-ignore-next-line
@var string $colBgColor and @psalm-ignore-var
@psalm-property-write string $colBgColor


Not cleaning up variable references with unset after you're done with them is highly irresponsible to begin with, so this screams "refactor me!" either way IMHO :-)

Also, the code is simple, why would refactoring be a problem? It would also probably make it easier to read in the future, not having to notice the & character. And it could prevent hard to trace bugs that might creep into the code.

@KIKOSoftware "Also, the code is simple, why would refactoring be a problem?" - The variables in question are comming from another module which can't be refactored atm. Therefor I would likle to have another solution for the mean time.

Nobody said anything about refactoring other code than the code in your question. It's simply looping over an array and setting any array value to Color::COLOR_HEADER;. At least, that's how I read it. I know this is not what you want to discuss, and I'm sorry for that, but refactoring might be the more sensible solution here.

https://docs.devsense.com/en/vs/code%20validation/configuration

@AlexHowansky Thank you very much! @suppress PHP0421 is the answer. Please add an answer..

"I can't change that file to fix the problem, but I can change the file to hide the problem." is quite the take.

@Sammitch Not giving the answer to the question is a different take. And quoting something that doesn't exist is ...

You can accomplish this in two ways. First, by creating a .editorconfig file in your project's base directory or the directory with the code in question, with the following contents:
[*.php]
php_diagnostic_php0421 = off

Second, inline via @suppress in a docblock:
/**
 * @suppress PHP0421
 */
function foo()
{
}

Note that the @suppress method works at the function or class level, not the specific line like PHPStan's @ignore does. See here for details.
